Power Automate + Power Apps + Azure Analyze Image
I'm new in the low-code world and I'm trying perform an integration of:
Power Apps > Power Automate > Azure Analyze Image service.
In Pwr Apps I get an image using a camera, and a button trigger the Automate.
The Automate receives the image in a JSON and I split the base 64 code for the image to use like a parameter to Analyze Image.
The problem is that today the Power Automate was updated to v2, and in this version my reference example code broke, because I need to use a Composer step to format the parameter to Analyzer Image step:
The Composer value should be:
{
"$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
"$content": "variables('varImgBase64')"
} 

But it generate a invalid expression.
So, I'm trying find a way to pass to an Analyze Image this base 64 image, some idea?
I just try concatenate in Compose:
concat('{"$content-type": "application/octet-stream", "$content": "', variables('varImgBase64'), '"}')
Was the Chat GPT anwser, but did not work.
Thanks for the help.
